# Values on Map not getting updated - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I am using onMapReady() function which gets called at the start of MapActivity which  implements OnMapReadyCallback.

It has  a spinner at the top on whose change of item I refresh values of particular region / country and it should get reflected in title after onPostExecute() .

All the things till onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask works fine in which I call again onMapReady(mMap) function to display new values , but it does not work

Below is my code

```
void callExchangeRateWebService() {

        CommonMethods.showProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this, "", "Fetching Exchange Rates...");
        new WebServiceCallTask(MapsActivity.this, "" + MantraSoapLinks.URL2+((CountryBean)(mSpinner1.getSelectedItem())).getmCountrySymbol(),"", "GET", "" ,new WebServiceCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object result) throws JSONException {
                CommonMethods.hideProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                JSONObject ratesObj = jObj.getJSONObject("rates");
                String baseStr = jObj.getString("base");
                String temp = ratesObj.toString().replace("{","");
                temp = temp.toString().replace("}","");
                 temp = temp.toString().replace("\"","");
                temp = temp.toString().replace("\"","");

                String[] str= temp.split(",");
                ArrayList<String> arry = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0 ;i <str.length;i++)
                {
                    arry.add(str[i]);
                }
                arry.add(baseStr+":1");

                String [] str1 = new String[arry.size()];
                for (int i = 0 ;i <arry.size();i++)
                {
                    str1[i] = arry.get(i).toString();
                }

                for(int i = 0 ; i<str1.length ; i++)
                {
                    CountryBean cn = new CountryBean();
                    cn.setmCountrySymbol((str1[i].split(":"))[0]);
                    cn.setmCurrencyValueMap((str1[i].split(":"))[1]);
                    db.updateCountryDetails(cn);
                }
                beanArry = db.getCountryDetails();
                onMapReady(mMap);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed(Object result) {

                CommonMethods.hideProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
            }
        }).execute();

    }
```

onMapReady() Function

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        /*// Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


        LatLng testindiA = new LatLng(-20, 150);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(testindiA).title("Yatin Test"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(testindiA));*/

        for (int i = 0;i<beanArry.size();i++)
        {
            LatLng ltLn = null;
            if(beanArry.get(i).getmLatitude()!=null) {
                ltLn = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(beanArry.get(i).getmLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(beanArry.get(i).getmLongitude()));

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ltLn).title(beanArry.get(i).getmCountryName()+" "+beanArry.get(i).getmCurrencyValueMap()));


                String str = beanArry.get(i).getmCountryName();
                str = str.toLowerCase();
                str = str.replace(" ","_");
                String PACKAGE_NAME =getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
                int imgId = getResources().getIdentifier(PACKAGE_NAME+":drawable/"+str , null, null);
                if(imgId!=0) {
                    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(imgId);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ltLn).icon(icon));
                }
                else
                {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ltLn).icon(null));
                }


                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ltLn));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: you dont have to call `onMapReady(mMap);`. just add marker normally and it will refresh itself, or call `mMap.clear();`, then add the marker.

Comment: Yes  worked with mMap.clear()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed out on `mMap.clear()` before updating Map .